# Two codes of Schema.org on product pages of an ecommerce website

Tags: e-commerce, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

There are two codes of Schema.org on product pages of an ecommerce website. First is `http://schema.org/Store` that includes store info. Another one `http://schema.org/Product` for product info.

Are two codes necessary on product pages? Because as of now with two codes i.e. one for store & another for product, there are no rich snippets showing up in SERPs.

Comment: *Necessary* for what?

Comment: Necessary to show up in SERPs. Because as of now with two codes i.e. one for store & another for product, there are no rich snippets showing up in SERPs

Answer (score 0):

What is or isn’t necessary for getting rich results is typically documented by the search engine service.

In case a rich result only needs a `Product` item, it doesn’t mean that you can’t also have a `Store` item. If a rich result doesn’t get displayed, it typically results from missing information, not from too much information.

Having a `Store` item can be beneficial for many reasons. It allows you to convey who is offering the `Product` (`Store` [`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer) [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer)), what else is offered by the store, where the store is located, etc.